# Error: StaticInjectorError on deployed Angular CLI project

Tags: angular, firebase, npm, github-pages

We have an Error when deploying our Angular CLI (v.1.7.1) project to GitHub Pages, and Firebase - both give the same result.

The `ng serve` works perfectly fine on `localhost:4200` and all is going well when building production `ng build --prod --base-href "https://<user-name>.github.io/<repo>/"` and `ngh` command, the files are being loaded,
but when we open it, nothing comes up (just the blank `index.html`) and we get the following error in the console:

```html
main.e17a4a9….bundle.js:1 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(Ru)[e -> e]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[e -> e]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for e!
    at e.get (main.e17a4a9….bundle.js:1)
    at main.e17a4a9….bundle.js:1
    at e (main.e17a4a9….bundle.js:1)
    at e.get (main.e17a4a9….bundle.js:1)
    at main.e17a4a9….bundle.js:1
    at e (main.e17a4a9….bundle.js:1)
    at e.get (main.e17a4a9….bundle.js:1)
    at Ii (main.e17a4a9….bundle.js:1)
    at main.e17a4a9….bundle.js:1
    at Ni (main.e17a4a9….bundle.js:1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your app with the optimization-feature disabled:

```
ng build --prod --optimization=false
```

This way, you'll see an error pointing to the real problem, instead of just "e".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular `4.2.4`, replace it with `4.4.3` in `package.json` file (just angular) and run `npm i`.

Might this will resolve your issue point. But if you are using `angular 5`, this issue has been already report in [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9383) of another library that suffered from this problem and it's resolved!